# OPP mysqli_query() expect two parameters...

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn object oriented programming. 
The problem what I have is how to add link under mysqli_query() inside the class.

In procedural style I just create a $variable with connection details and then using it inside the mysqli_query($variable, $sql) etc.

In my class I have function connect() which will connect to database and return true but Haw can I use it inside my mysqli_query() please? please see the code here:

```
    <?php

class DB {
    protected $db_name = 'OOP_forum';
    protected $db_user = 'Marcel';
    protected $db_pass = *****;
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';


    public function connect() {

        $connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysqli_select_db($connection, $this->db_name);

        return true;
    }

    public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow = false)  {

        $resultArray = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowSet)) {
            arraypush($resultArray, $row);
        }

          if($singleRow==true) {
              return $resultArray[0];
          }else {
                 return $resultArray; }
        }


      public function select ($table, $where, $column = '*')  {
          $sql = "SELECT $column FROM $table WHERE $where";
          $result = mysqli_query($sql);

              if(mysqli_num_row($result) == 1 ){
                 return $this->processRowSet($result, true);
               } else
                  { return $this->processsRowSet($result);
             }
          }



      public function update ($data, $table, $where)    {

                      foreach ($data as $column->$value) {

                          $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $column = $value WHERE $where";
                          mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
                             }
                          return true;
                      } 

      public function delete ($table, $column, $where)  {
          $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $column = $where";

              if (query($sql)=== TRUE) {
              echo "Record Deleted sucessfully";
          }else {
              echo "Error deleting record: " . $connection->error;
          }

      }               

      public function insert($data, $table)  {

             $columns = "";
             $values = "";

             foreach ($data as $column->$value) {

                 $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "": ", " ;
                 $columns .= $column;
                 $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
                 $values .= $value;
                    }


             $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
             mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

             return mysqli_insert_id();
              }      

          } 


?>
```

Comment: Why you're using procedural mysqli, if you're learning OOP syntax?

Comment: you have to pass your connection object as a first parameter  here:- `$result = mysqli_query($sql);`

Comment: Thanks for comments. That is what I am trying to do to pass the connection as the first parameter to mysqli_query(something, $sql) but not sure how to achieve that from my connect function which returns true. will study more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to learn OOP programming you have to learn basic OOP syntax.

In order to do so forget for a while about creating your own classes and learn how to use already made ones. So, first of all learn how to use mysqli. Which is already a class.

Better yet, learn PDO instead, as, unlike mysqli, it's already a ready to use database access class, with it you don't need functions like processRowSet, for example.